# Switch from facebook-ios-sdk to facebook-swift-sdk, use of FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate in new code

Tags: swift, facebook

I am switching from Facebook iOS SDK to Facebook Swift SDK.

I want to be notified of the results of app invite. This is what I have in old code:

```
extension VolumesListViewController: FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate {

    public func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
        ...
    }


    func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It seems that in Swift SDK, this DialogDelegate is encapsulated into the framework and not opened for implementation:

So, this is the SDKDelegate:

```
extension AppInvite {
    internal class SDKDelegate: NSObject, FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate {
        internal var completion: ((Result) -> Void)?

        func setupAsDelegateFor(_ dialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog) {
          // We need for the connection to retain us,
          // so we can stick around and keep calling into handlers,
          // as long as the connection is alive/sending messages.
          objc_setAssociatedObject(dialog,     Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(), self, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
          dialog.delegate = self
        }

        func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog?, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable: Any]?) {
           completion?(.success(results?.keyValueFlatMap { ($0 as? String, $1 as? String) } ?? [:]))
        }

        func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog?, didFailWithError error: Error) {
          completion?(.failed(error))
        }
    }
 }
```

How to achieve the same with notifications, without using the old framework?

My reason is this:

> The frameworks for the Facebook SDK in Swift are organized in the same way as the Facebook SDK for iOS . They also depend upon the Facebook SDK for iOS, although this may change at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for everything to become clear I just have to post a question on SO:

This is what I've found: I can use trailing closure for the AppInvite.Dialog.show(from:invite:) to have feedback from the Dialog:

```
let appInvite = AppInvite(appLink: URL(string: "http://eggheadgames.com/cryptograms")!)
do {
    try AppInvite.Dialog.show(from: self, invite: appInvite) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
            Logger.logUIEvent("InviteFriend", label: "called")
        case .failed(_):
            Logger.logUIEvent("InviteFriend", label: "unavailable")
        }
    }
} catch _ {
    Logger.logUIEvent("InviteFriend", label: "unavailable")
}
```